# Java importing Package wont work [Compiler throwing missleading Errors]

Tags: java, import

When I try to import another package, it throws some weird error.
I'm working with eclipse and imported the package `humanBeeings` like this: 
[image]

The Error says: Syntax error, @ expected

I dont know how to fix this anybody got an idea?
I placed the @ on several places already but nothing seems to work

The code of the list Collection Class is the following:

```
package listCollection;
import humanBeeings.Human;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

    public class listCollection {
        List<Human> list = new LinkedList <Human>(); // <> zur spezifizierung der Objektklasse, nur Objekte dieser Klasse dürfen in die Liste
        list.add(new Human("Dennis", 20));
        list.add(new Human("vladimir", 33));
        for (Human h: list) { // für das Objekt der Objektklasse Human in der List
            System.out.println(h.getName());
        }
    }
```

The code of the Human Class looks like this..

```
package humanBeeings;

    public class Human {
        // Objekteigenschaften
        private String name;
        private int age;
        // Konstrucktoren
        public Human(String name, int age){
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }
        // Accessoren/Methoden
        public void setName(String name){
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getName(){
            return this.name;
        }
        public void setAge(int age){
            this.age = age;
        }
        public int getAge(){
            return this.age;
        }
        //Main
        public static void main(String[] args){
            // Some actions here...
        }
    }
```

Comment: add some code using `ctrl+c` - `ctrl+v`

Comment: close and open your file

Comment: and where is your `main` method?

Comment: the main method is somewhere else in the human class..

Comment: Off-topic, but use Java naming conventions and start name of your class with upper-case.

Comment: I see a couple of small errors in your code that may aren't directly related to your problem. Package names are traditionally all  lowercase (`humanBeeings` -> `humanbeeings`;`listCollection` -> `listcollection`) and class names should start with a capital letter (`listCollection` -> `ListCollection`).

Comment: thanks @ dohaqatar i will change that

Comment: Your title is very general. Please edit it into something related to problem from your question.

Comment: i did but i dont understand why this question is a duplication of the mentioned above ones. i thought i coulndt import the package because the compiler throwed some wierd errors...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statements that you've written do not appear inside a method. Place them inside a method, like so:

```
public void testMyListCollection() {
    List<Human> list = new LinkedList <Human>();
    // etcetera
}
```

It is important for the Java compiler that you follow the syntax of Java closely. In this particular example you placed statements inside the class body, not inside a method body. The only type of statements allowed in a class body are "assignments", i.e. when you assign a value to an instance variable:

```
public class Example {
    private int myValue = 3 + 3; // A statement inside a class body,
                                 // because it is part of an assignment
}
```

Comment: the question isn't about this

Comment: I think it is; AFAICS the compiler is confused because statements appear inside a class body, where they aren't expected.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko ...because?

Comment: @Pshemo I thought that the error has been in package... but you're right +1

Comment: yeah this one worked but why is the compiler throwing some wierd errors then?!

Comment: @TeaTime Since `list.add(new Human("Dennis", 20));` is not valid statement at this place, compiler informs you that it expects something valid. It could be for instance start of annotation like `@Override` and you ware informed about such possibility.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you want your class to do, but this will print your list when called...

```
package listCollection;

import humanBeeings.Human;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class listCollection {

    public static void printHumans() {
        List<Human> list = new LinkedList();
        list.add(new Human("Dennis", 20));
        list.add(new Human("vladimir", 33));
        for (Human h : list) {
            System.out.println(h.getName());
        }
    }
}
```